# django-registration-redux change password link

Tags: python, django

I am using django-registrations-redux. In my template, I have the following:

html:

```
<li><a href="/accounts/password/change">Change Password</a></li>
```

and the urls.py is:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

if I go to the following

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/
```

I get the list of all the links that works under accounts/ such as login, logout and register...etc
If i go to accounts/login it works really fine but if i go to /accounts/password/change in the case of the html provided above, the page redirects to an admin look and feel page witha Django Administration banner on the top of the page.

any help? am i missing anything?

edit:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^home/', "asset.views.home", name="home"),
url(r'^add_asset/', "asset.views.add_asset", name="add_asset"),
url(r'^update_asset/(?P<id>\d+)/$', "asset.views.update_asset", name="update_asset"),
url(r'^asset_detail/(?P<slug_asset_desc>[\w\-]+)/$', "asset.views.asset_detail", name='asset_detail'),
url(r'^search/$', "asset.views.search_asset", name="search"),
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),]
```

Answer (score 0):

The full url for password changing is "password/change/" with slash at the end. Maybe in your settings you set [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#append-slash) to false and it's can't find "password/change" url. Try to use pattern name in your html code:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'auth_password_change' %}">Change Password</a></li>
```

Comment: I am appending slash, did that after i posted here. Still no result. I tried the code you provided, still nothing also.

Comment: Add your urls.py to question

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe it's doesn't fix your problem, but try write include(admin.site.urls) instead of admin.site.urls . Add your settings.py to question

Comment: I solved the problem by moving the app name the beginning of the INSTALLED_APPS, just before django.contrib.admin :)

Comment: Had same problem and moving 'registration' app to top of INSTALLED_APPS fixed it.  It now uses the proper template instead of looking like django admin.